# How to plot the result from highest defining the number of bars with barssince

Tags: pine-script, trading

Try to plot the value of the highest bars between current bar and the last cross of `ema(50)` and `ema(200)` using `barssince(cross(ema50,ema200))`. The function `highest()` wants an `integer` and the Barssince gives a `series integer`. All variants getting the error that pine connot compile with error:

> line 4: Cannot call `highest` with arguments (series[integer]);
>   available overloads: highest(series, integer) => series;
>   highest(integer) => series Script.

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")
o = 0
o := highest(barssince(cross(sma(close,50),sma(close,200))))
plot(o, color = yellow)
```

The ema cross is just an example. The `highest()` function with a calculated number of bars with `barssince` is my goal.

How do I convert the result form barssince to an integer accepted by `highest()`?
Or is there a different solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the function highest by yourself:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", max_bars_back=5000)

highest_pine(src, len) =>
    max = src[0]
    for i = 1 to len
        if src[i] > max
            max := src[i]
    max

o = 0.0
o := highest_pine(close, barssince(cross(sma(close,50),sma(close,200))))
plot(o, color = green)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference is pretty confusing, but after playing around with your function a bit I managed to make it work:

There are two overloads for the `highest()` function:
- `highest(length)`, this one takes an `integer` and returns a series
- `highest(source, length)`, this one takes a `series` and an `integer`
There is a hint in the function reference, saying that `One arg version: x is a length. Algorithm uses high as a source series.`

Checking the reference for `barssince()` I see that it takes a `bool` (logical condition) and returns a series of `integer`.

Now it is clear that the `highest(barssince(true))` is not the correct syntax because `barssince()` will return a `series` and not an `integer`, while `highest()` expects and integer or a series **and** and integer.

From poking around and searching online I reached a conclusion that it is not possible to have a variable of `integer` in pine script that is not a `series` at the same time.
This leads me to believe that the `highest()` function cannot be used dynamically.

I was able to mimic the behavior using `if` statement, along with the help of [this migration guide](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Pine_Version_3_Migration_Guide)

This is the version of the script that works for me, it plots a line at the `max()` of the highs, resetting if there is a new MA cross.

```
//@version=3
study("High since SMA Cross")

fast_sma = sma(close,10)
slow_sma = sma(close,20)

high_since_cross = 0.0
resistance = if(cross(fast_sma, slow_sma))
    high
else
    max(nz(high_since_cross[1]), high)
plot(resistance, color=yellow)
```

Comment: Thanks for the details answer. I tried this code, but "High_since_cross"  gets never a  number different from 0. The plot of resistance just follows the high price without ever getting a 0.

The max(nz... line gives me a new idea. Will post the outcome but might take a few days.

Comment: interesting, [this](https://www.tradingview.com/x/ugEJM3Vg/) is what i get if I copy paste the script. Maybe the indent of the `if` block got broken ?

Comment: after plotting the SMAs I see that the script is really not working well, I think this is because we're not using `crossover` and `crossunder` in place of `cross` and this messes up with the `high` (we need to use `min` and `low`in case of `crossunder` and `max` and `high` in case of crossover.